# Many strange issues with 2009 Macbook Pro running 10.10.5

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic, cpu

my wifes macbook pro started acting very strange this evening, and i can't seem to figure out what is wrong with it at all. here is a list of various issues that all seemingly started tonight:

ReportCrash using between 90 - 150% cpu

syslogd using over 150% cpu (although not at the same time as ReportCrash)

various programs not opening, including: mail, photos, preview, chrome, app store

very intermittent internet connection (via wi-fi)

safari stating the certificate for google.com is not trusted

system crash, followed by kernal panic error message after restart

system crash during restart

spotlight search not showing applications in results, despite the option being ticked in preferences

various processes (not responding), including: steam helper, adobe creative cloud

(when trying to upgrade to el capitan) : el capitan upgrade asking for password to install, accepting password but not progressing, asking for password again, ad infinitum

"All My Files" folder showing no files.

etc, etc, etc

if this were a windows pc i might be able to figure it out, but i am new to OS X and this seems well beyond my understanding. thank you in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be a failing HD. You could try to look into the console.app, found here:

```
/Application/Utilities/Console.app
```

If the log shows IO-Errors it's time to replace the HD.

There are of course other explanation, f.e. a corrupt Kernel extension or even a defective Font, but as i said it sounds like the HD.

Comment: any idea what logs i should be looking at specifically? there's a lot of options on here and i'm not well versed (trying to learn though)

Comment: The First entry, "system Log Queries > All Messages" should display all you need (see an example here: https://support.omnigroup.com/assets/article_img/support/osx-console-window.png).

Comment: @JamesStansell If it needs replaced, upgrade to an SSD, like one from the Intel 530 series, just definitely not a Samsung.

Comment: checked the system log and there were 16 I/O errors within one second, looks like roughly the time the system was started. there are, however, 3297 errors that say the same thing about safari: nsurlstoraged: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=users/(username)/library/caches/com.apple.safari/cache.db

Comment: @RedEagle2000 it actually already has an SSD, a PNY 120gb. wondering why you recommend against Samsung though, my 830 Pro SSD has been working great for years

Comment: @RedEagle: I was wondering the same as James - why against Samsung. I prefer Samsung and had very good experience with them.

Answer (score 0):

replaced hard drive, reinstalled el capitan. everything seems to be working so far